# How to create a key mapping to save file in any mode?

Tags: key-bindings

I want to define `<C-s>` to save current editing file in any mode.
`map <C-s> :call StripWhitespace()<CR>` works fine in normal mode. But if I'm in insert mode, always need to `Esc` before saving.

Tried below methods, but failed.
`imap <C-s> :call StripWhitespace()<CR>`

```
function! My_Force_Save()
   if mode() != 'n'
      exe "normal! \<esc>"
   endif
   call StripWhitespace()
endfunction
```

---

```
function! StripWhitespace ()
    let save_cursor = getpos(".")
    let old_query = getreg('/')
    :%s/\s\+$//e
    call setpos('.', save_cursor)
    call setreg('/', old_query)
    exe ":w!"
endfunction
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:map` command you tried works in normal,
visual, and operator pending modes, and the
`:imap` command works in insert mode, so you're
going to need both, but you're also going to need
to make a few changes.

Firstly, you should always use the non-recursive
`nore` forms of the various map commands unless
you have a specific reason not to.

Next, note that the map commands work as though
you are typing out the things you map to. When you
type a colon in visual mode, the command-line is
pre-populated with a `:'<,'>` range. We don't want
to pass this range to the `:call` command, so we
need to clear it first with <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd>:

```
noremap <C-S> :<C-U>call StripWhitespace()<CR>
```

Similarly, to call a function from an insert mode
map, you need to include the <kbd>Esc</kbd> in
your mapping:

```
inoremap <C-S> <Esc>:call StripWhitespace()<CR>
```

Even better, use <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> to perform a single command and remain in insert mode:

```
inoremap <C-S> <C-O>:call StripWhitespace()<CR>
```

See `:help i_CTRL-O`

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/343/rich @Rich, Found an issue: In normal mode, 'dd' delete a line, after this 'C-s' is not working.

Comment: Not sure why `inoremap` is not working. Need to use `map <C-S> <Esc>:call StripWhitespace()<CR>`

Comment: @Fisher You need both! See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details. Now I understand the difference. Why I can't @Rich in the beginning?